# Can Google App Engine support multiple domains pointing at a single appsot.com (or apps domain) GAE app?

Tags: google-app-engine

Firstly, I understand how I can use google apps to point a domain (my company's domain say 'greatapp.com' at 'greatapp.appspot.com' no problems there.

I also understand that once I've got it onto 'greatapp.com' I can use wildcard hostnames to host the app on '*.greatapp.com' no issues there.

The point is that the application I'm thinking about building would be one which I would charge companies to use, and it would probably need to be co-branded, and therefore the company might want to use their own domains for displaying their data to customers, so data.companyname.com instead of companyname.greatapp.com.

Would GAE accept a domain pointed by the company via CNAME (or whatever) or is that not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James, have a look at this http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/cookbook/dynamic-subdomains/ for code example. It is possible.

One thing to note is that AppEngine doesn't allow naked domain (domain without www). So when you are setting up a custom domain pointing to your AppEngine instance, you are setting up a CNAME for www.